# How to select object type when exporting to csv in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, export-to-csv

My array `$list` contains multiple object types. One is a string and one is a 
`PSCustomObject`.

When I pipe it to `Export-Csv`, all I get is the first object that is string which returns useless results.

```
PS C:\data\functions> $list | gm


   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition                                                                           
----             ----------            ----------                                                                           
Clone            Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()                              
CompareTo        Method                int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(string strB), int IComparable.Co...


--- Output removed ----

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
Direction   NoteProperty string Direction=both         
Hostname    NoteProperty string Hostname=Desktop1         
Target      NoteProperty string Target=Rental                

PS C:\data\functions> $list| Export-Csv -Path "c:\data\list.txt" -NoTypeInformation

PS C:\data\functions> Get-Content "C:\data\list.txt"
"Length"
"5"
```

I have tried to cast the object to PSCustomObject by using 
`[PSCustomObject] $list` and `[PSCustomObject[]] $list` .
I have tried `$list | out-File -FilePath "c:\data\list.txt"`. That does give me the contents of the array as it is displayed in the terminal

```
hello

Hostname  : Desktop1
Target    : Rental

Hostname  : Desktop2
Target    : Rental

Hostname  : Desktop3
Target    : Rental

Hostname  : Desktop4
Target    : Rental
```

I expect to get a CSV-file

Comment: If you ***want*** to produce an invalid csv, do so by first converting the array with `ConvertTo-Csv` and then combine with your string and write to a file with `Set-Content` or `Out-File`

Comment: `$list | Where-Object {$_ -is [PSCustomObject]} | Export-Csv ...`?

Comment: @iRon that's not going to work - `[PSCustomObject]` on its own resolves to `[psobject]`, and everything in PowerShell is a `[psobject]` :) this should do the trick: `$list |? {$_ -isnot [string]} |Export-Csv ...`

Comment: @Mathias, classic mistake, I should have known/test it. I was actually trying to force some clarification, whether Fredrik wants a filtered valid CSV file or invalid CSV with a string in the top. This is unclear from the question.

Comment: @iRon: Confusingly, type accelerator `[pscustomobject]` is the same as `[psobject]`, however, `-is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]` works reliably.

Comment: Fredrik, how do you expect the string to be represented in the CSV? Or do you really just want to filter the strings out (in which case @MathiasR.Jessen's command will help)? Mathias, please see my previous comment re `-is`, and the associated `-as` pitfall discussed in https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4343

Answer (score 1):

I would say you have to select the properties you want, or else it won't save them all.

```
$a = [pscustomobject]@{name='Joe'}
$b = [pscustomobject]@{address='here'}
$a,$b | select name,address | export-csv all.csv
```